# Can you pass by reference in PeopleCode?

Tags: pass-by-reference, peoplesoft

I'm new to PeopleCode and as I'm learning functions, I noticed that in PeopleCode, we'd normally pass value using %PATIENT_ID. A friend told me that you can also pass by reference in PeopleCode but how?

Answer (score 7):

PeopleCode passes by reference for functions.

```
Function addOne(&num As integer)    
    &num = &num + 1 
End-Function;

Local integer &val = 9;
addOne(&val);
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0,String(&val));
```

Results in 10

If you are using App Classes it behaves differently
for methods:

- Pass by value for simple types (string, int, number,etc)
- Pass by reference for objects (rowsets, records, app classes)
- Can pass by reference for simple types using the OUT keyword in the parameter list

  `method addOne(&num as integer out)`

Answer (score 1):

Functions which are defined in the same context as the executing code, e.g. page/component/record/field event PeopleCode, always consider parameters as refernces.

Within Application Classes, parameters of simple types on methods can be defined with the 'out' key word to state that they are a references. Methods also automatically pass parameters as references for complex types. Think: "If there is a lot of data, it is a reference"

Answer (score 1):

This documentation will be very helpful for you.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26239_01/pt851h3/eng/psbooks/tpcr/chapter.htm?File=tpcr/htm/tpcr07.htm

> **Passing Parameters with Object Data Types**
>
> Parameters with object data types are always passed by reference:
>
> ```
> /* argument passed by reference  */
> method storeInfo(&f as File);
> ```
>
> If you specify the out modifier for a method parameter with an object
>   data type, it becomes a reference parameter. This means that the
>   parameter variable is passed by reference instead of the object that
>   it is pointing at when passed.
>
> For example, if you pass an object parameter with the out modifier:
>
> ```
> method myMethod(&arg as MyObjectClass);
>
> Local MyObjectClass &o1 = create MyObjectClass("A");
> Local MyOtherObjectClass &o2 = create MyOtherObjectClass();
>
> &o2.myMethod(&o1);
>
> And inside myMethod this occurs:
> Method myMethod
>    &arg  =  create MyObjectClass("B");
> end-method;
> ```
>
> Since the method argument is reassigned within the body of myMethod,
>   &o1 does not point at the new instance of MyObjectClass (initialized
>   with "B") after the method call completes. This is because &o1 still
>   references the original instance of MyObjectClass.
>
> However, if &o1 had been passed with the out modifier, after the
>   method call completes, &o1 points at whatever the parameter was last
>   assigned to; in this case, the new instance of MyObjectClass. The
>   parameter, rather than the object, is passed by reference.    Using
>   the Out Specification for a Parameter
>
> In the following example, a class, AddStuff, has a single public
>   method, DoAdd. This adds two numbers together, then assigns them as
>   different numbers. In the signature of the method declaration, the
>   first parameter is not declared with an out statement, while the
>   second one is.
>
> ```
> class AddStuff
>    ​method DoAdd(&P1 as number, &P2 as number out);
> ​end-class;
>
> method DoAdd
>    &X = &P1 + &P2;
>    &P1 = 1;
>    &P2 = 2;
> end-method;
> ```
>
> In the following PeopleCode example, an object named &Aref is
>   instantiated from the class AddStuff. Two parameters, &I and &J are
>   also defined.
>
> ```
> local AddStuff &Aref = Create AddStuff();
> local number &I = 10;
> local number &J = 20;
> ```
>
> The following code example is correct. &J is changed, because of the
>   outstatement in the method signature, and because the value is being
>   passed by reference. The value of &I is not updated.
>
> ```
> &Aref.DoAdd(&I, &J); /* changes &J but not &I */
> ```
>
> The following code example causes a design time error. The second
>   parameter must be passed by reference, not by value.
>
> ```
> &Aref.DoAdd(10, 20); /* error - second argument not variable */
> ```